# PeopleSoft - Cannot process SOAP fault messages after consuming web service

Tags: web-services, soap, peoplesoft

PT 8.50.15

We have a new integration with a third party system.  They have provided the wsdl and I have used the consume web service wizard to consume it into PeopleSoft.  All this does is give you the stub messages with a schema attached to each.  I have written some peoplecode to send a test message out to the webservice.  When the webservice returns a valid result, I have no problems.  However, when the webservice returns a fault message, I get the following error:

Integration Gateway - HttpTargetConnector:ExternalApplicationException.  Http status code HttpStatusCode returned : 500. (158,10623)

HttpTargetConnector:ExternalApplicationException. External System responded with an Error status. For Http Status Code explanation please check Http protocol Specifications.

I know the webservice is returning the fault message b/c I have tried the same thing in SOAPUI.  Does anyone know why PeopleSoft throws up this error ONLY on the fault message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the routing that you are using, click the 'User Exception' check box.  Then you will not get the HTTP 500 error.  Evaluate the response from the response message.  If it's not zero, you will then be able to parse the SOAP fault and see what the returned faultstring is.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the prior response, the 500 error you are seeing should be followed by any soap fault coming back with the response in the errorLog.html file on your gateway (or msgLog depending on the ig.log.level setting in your integrationgateway.properties file.   Check the 'response' section, as well as the stack trace for additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Get your Service operation corrected. I Had same issue, After i changed the SO in this code it started working

```
&msgRequest = CreateMessage(Operation.Operation_name, %IntBroker_Request);
```